# running scrapy CrawlerProcess as async

Tags: scrapy, python-asyncio

i would like to run scrapy along with another asyncio script in the same file, but am unable to.
(using the [asyncio reactor](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/asyncio.html) in the settings:
`# TWISTED_REACTOR = "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor"`)

```
asyncio.run(playwright_script())
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl(TestSpider)
process.start()
```

this raises the error:

> RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread'.

i'm guessing because the previous run command blocks the event loop?

i have tried to add the scrapy commands into a coroutine like so:

```
async def run_scrapy():
    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    process.crawl(TestSpider)
    process.start()

asyncio.run(run_scrapy_script())
```

but receive the error:

> RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

**How do i properly configure the scrapy CrawlerProcess to run on my asyncio loop?**